# BDI logic or KARO framework solver - are there solvers for any new logic?

Tags: logic, satisfiability, first-order-logic, linear-temporal-logic

I am reading about agent logics and especially affective agents. There are BDI logics and combination of logics called KARO framework that considers those questions. All those logics seem to be specified and evaluated rather completely - so - are there implementation of this logics as solver or reasoner software.

If they are open source projects I would be more than happy to particiapte and contribute to them but I am afraid - Google gives nothing. Maybe there are still some projects that are hidden in the deep web and is not found by Google?

Btw. There are many logics - do they have their own solvers?